# How do you set a cell to null in datagrip?

Tags: datagrip

Is there a quick way without diving into sql to set a particular attribute back to null? entering in "" doesn't work.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You can either:

1. Select the field, right-click, and select "Set NULL"
2. Select the field, press CTRL+ALT+N (on Windows).

Note that boolean fields will show up as a box filled with a dash (-) when null.

If the "Set NULL" option is not appearing, you might need to refresh the schema which you can do by clicking the synchronize button:

[image]

or by pressing Ctrl+Alt+Y (on Windows).

Comment: Sorry but I think thats poor design.. it should be smart enough ...as it does with most things...and recognize me typing "N-U-L-L" and know what I mean. Right clicking wasn't my first thought.

Comment: Couldn't find the "Set NULL" option on 2017.2 version.

Comment: Sometimes if you don't have "SET NULL" in the right-click, you need to refresh your schema. Right click on the table and Synchronize (Ctrl Alt Y)

Comment: Set NULL is only displayed for nullable fields

Comment: On macOS, you can also right click the entry and select "set NULL" or use this shortcut <command><option>n to set null.

Comment: I was clicking on "Reload page" and "Set NULL" did not appear. As you said you need to press "Refresh" on the schema not "Reload page". They have the same icon

Answer (score 9):

If set null is not an option, try synchronizing the table schema. Right click the table and Synchronize `(Ctrl-Alt-Y)`

Answer (score 4):

In Windows, there are two easy ways:

1. Select specific field and then press `Ctrl+Alt+N`
2. Right click on the specific field and then select `Set NULL`

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Also, be sure that your field is `nullable` otherwise, DataGrip WILL NOT present the `Set NULL` option :)